# PHP soap result status OK but there is no any items. SOAPUI gives status ok and items too

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soapui

Could you help me please -?
When I run a SOAP request in PHP, I am getting result success but there are no items in the result.
Like this below...

```
<?php


    $wsdl='https://api.n11.com/ws/SapCommissionEInvoiceDetailService.wsdl';
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl);
    $searchData = array(
                    "auth" => array( 
                                            "appKey" => '***********', 
                                            "appSecret" => '*******'),
                    "date" => '2020-06');

                                
    
    $result = $soap->GetSapCommissionEInvoiceDetail($searchData);
    
    
    // Echo the result
    echo "<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>";

    ?>
```

When I run the request via SOAPUI I am getting all the expected items.
Like this below...

[SOAPUI request and responce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44qws.png)

Could you tell me what is my wrong, please?

When I call other methods in this api I am getting all items without any problem. But in this method(GetSapCommissionEInvoiceDetail) I have a big problem. Please help - I've spent seven days looking for a solution.

UPDATE

OUTPUT (result) of echo is:

---

stdClass Object
(
[result] => stdClass Object
(
[status] => success
)

```
[commissionInvoiceDetail] => stdClass Object
    (
        [commissionInvoiceDetailDataList] => stdClass Object
            (
            )

    )
```

### )

UPDATE_2:
i have added 2 rows to catch errors.

```
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($soap->__getLastRequest()) . "\n";
    echo "Response:\n" . htmlentities($soap->__getLastResponse()) . "\n";
```

The result of __getLastReques is:

```
REQUEST: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.n11.com/ws/schemas"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetSapCommissionEInvoiceDetailRequest><auth><appKey>*************</appKey><appSecret>**************</appSecret></auth><date>2020-06</date></ns1:GetSapCommissionEInvoiceDetailRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And the result of getLastResponse is:

```
Response: <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header/><env:Body><ns3:GetSapCommissionEInvoiceDetailResponse xmlns="" xmlns:ns3="http://www.n11.com/ws/schemas"><result><status>success</status></result><commissionInvoiceDetail><commissionInvoiceDetailDataList><commissionInvoiceItemDetailData><addOrder>0,00</addOrder><belnr>0400201769</belnr><malzemeKodu></malzemeKodu><miktar>1</miktar><orderItemId>208851060</orderItemId><orderNumber>205978544774</orderNumber><pazarlamaGeliri>0,00</pazarlamaGeliri><saticiId></saticiId><tamamlanmaTarihi>08.06.2020</tamamlanmaTarihi><transactionDDText>Satış Kargo (SPP)</transactionDDText><transactionType>SKS</transactionType><tutar>8,34</tutar><vadeFarki>0,00</vadeFarki></commissionInvoiceItemDetailData><commissionInvoiceItemDetailData><addOrder>0,00</addOrder><belnr>0400201769</belnr><malzemeKodu></malzemeKodu><miktar>1</miktar><orderItemId>208785323</orderItemId><orderNumber>205387444774</orderNumber>
```

so the result of XML is not NULL. it is perfect. But the result of echo is:

```
stdClass Object
```

(
[result] => stdClass Object
(
[status] => success
)

```
[commissionInvoiceDetail] => stdClass Object
    (
        [commissionInvoiceDetailDataList] => stdClass Object
            (
            )

    )
```

)

the result of echo is NULL. So i am doing some mistakes when i print results. HELP PLSSSSSS )))

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please include the output from `echo "<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>";` in your answer? It may give readers more context to help you.

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => success
        )

    [commissionInvoiceDetail] => stdClass Object
        (
            [commissionInvoiceDetailDataList] => stdClass Object
                (
                )

        )

)

Comment: I updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any way of testing this with the API you're trying to use - but try:

```
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, [
  'features' => SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE,
  'exceptions' => true
]);
$soap->__setSoapHeaders([]);
```

It could be that the PHP soap client is having a hard time interpreting the type of XML array being returned from the API. If nothing else, the `exceptions` key being true might alert you to some other problem.

Comment: Added 2 rows to my request: 
  
echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($soap->__getLastRequest()) . "\n";echo "</br>";echo "</br>";
  echo "Response:\n" . htmlentities($soap->__getLastResponse()) . "\n";echo "</br>";echo "</br>";

Comment: and i have updated my question to answer your suggests. Could you check pls UPDATE_2